# Notepad++ "join lines" applies to the selected text, how to instead join current line to next one

Tags: notepad++

Notepad "join lines" is a bit different than in other editors: instead it applies to selected text.

How does one get the more standard current-line based join lines" - in which one puts the cursor on a line (no selection required!!) and the command .. joins lines?

Comment: If you don't make a selection, how is it supposed to know what lines you want to join? As far as "split", what's wrong with the Enter key? It splits the line at the current cursor position.

Comment: Any other editor I am aware of uses "join" to signify to append the next line to the end of the line of the cursor.  No text need be selected - after all there is ALWAYS a current cursor line which is all that is required. The "split" does NOT break the current line into two at the cursor.  I have CTRL-I (default) for split and it does nothing.

Comment: Sorry, but you can append the next line to the end of the current line by hitting End and then Del, and the Enter key certainly does split the line at the current cursor position (by adding a CR or CRLF character). "Any other editor" that you're aware of such as...? Oh, wait... What OS are you using? I'm referring to NP++ on Windows; perhaps you're using something else?

Comment: @ken I am not going to argue about functionality of Join. i want one key. Every other significant (not plain old notepad.exe..) has it. My current usages are IJ, vim, editplus, ultraedit. they all have it.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to argue. You asked the question here, and I was trying to clarify the issue you feel you have because, quite frankly, I don't see it. If the other editors have the functionality you want, you should probably use one of them instead, since you have such a wide selection of editors that behave in what you consider to be the "right way".

Comment: And I like notepad++ in a number of ways. I like it enough to make the effort to put a question on SOF. I like it enough to use it and to want to close the gap on a small-ish feature. The answer I usually hope will also bring to light potentially more inner workings of this editor that i am using for only two months.

Comment: I have toned down the question and focused it.

Comment: I upvoted one of your responses because the "Split Line" does make sense as you described it. The join lines is still an oustanding question.

Comment: I work in kde, but have windows installs. I fired up windows, updated npp and tested join lines [ctrl+j) to the join lines in kate/kwrite (ctrl+j) in TDE 3.5.13. I see the issue. With kate/kwrite, merely having the cursor present on a line and pressing ctrl+j joins the next with the current. On npp, nothing occurs unless a selection is present. Npp doesn't seem to have default that says `if (!selecttion) join (next,prev)`. Seems you have either stumbled upon a bug or needed feature request. You may file one at: http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/

Comment: thx I will do that. Mind to upvote?  I feel gives validation to my question.

Comment: I actually tried to submit a bug before but was unable to navigate the registration process. Specifically a logon was created for np++ but creating a bug required a sourceforge logon and i had issues with sf. Would you mind to do the favor?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Please make your comment an answer and I will accept

Comment: Ok done. I'm glad I was able to help. Hopefully they can get this issue fixed in short order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work in kde, but have windows installs. I fired up windows, updated npp and tested join lines [ctrl+j) to the join lines in kate/kwrite (ctrl+j) in TDE 3.5.13. I see the issue. With kate/kwrite, merely having the cursor present on a line and pressing ctrl+j joins the next with the current. On npp, nothing occurs unless a selection is present. Npp doesn't seem to have default that says `if (!selecttion) join (next,prev)`. Seems you have either stumbled upon a bug or needed feature request. You may file one at: [**sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs**](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/)